# React useEffect with property as dependency makes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component:

```
const MyComp : React.FC<{ editing?: Data }> = ({editing = { title = '', description = '', date: new Date() } }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Data>({...editing})
    useEffect(() => setData({...editing}), [editing])
    return (/* use data inside here to render component */)
}
```

The problem is that the useEffect is looping, so React is detecting that the editing prop is changing every, the thing is that i use MyComp without any props like this:

```
<MyComp></MyComp>
```

This is really confusing me, i'm kinda lost now on how React works, any ideas on why is this happening?

Comment: If `editing` is not specified as a prop, the default will be used. And it'll be a different default instance for each render and that will see the effect run and that will set the state and that will render ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `editing` is an object. Objects are compared by reference. If you don't pass the prop `editing` to the component, in each render, `editing` will receive a new link in memory, because you passing a default value to it. So `useEffect` will assume that dependencies have changed.

You can set primitive types to dependencies.

```
const MyComp : React.FC<{ editing?: Data }> = ({editing = { title = '', description = '', date: new Date() } }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<Data>({...editing})
    useEffect(() => setData({...editing}), [editing.title, editing.description, editing.date.getTime()])
    return (/* use data inside here to render component */)
}
```

Comment: Wow that was it, i was getting strange behaviors if i changed from `{...editing}` to just `editing`, really didn't get why, but i changed the code to this: `editing = undefined` and `useState(editing || { /*default data here*/ })`, inside useEffect just check if editing isn't undefined and setData, works fine now, thanks for the answer

Comment: This is correct. Another alternative would be to declare the default object as a const outside of the function. This would lead to the same object reference being used each render

Answer (score 4):

It happens because useEffect uses shallow comparison.
You can either destructure the object

```
const {param1, param2} = editing;
useEffect(() => {
//logic goes here
}, [param1, param2]);
```

Or write a custom hook that uses Lodash isEqual for example